# Concordance des temps: conditionnel et imparfait

Tags: concordance-des-temps, discours-indirect

J'aimerais bien comprendre l'utilisation du conditionnel et de l'imparfait dans un propos indirect dans le passé. Il y a une phrase:

> Elle m'a dit: "La porte sera installée dans 3 jours"

J'envisage deux situations:

- Elle l'a dit lundi. Nous sommes mardi. L’événement est dans le futur *par rapport au moment de mon discours*. Alors, j'utilise le conditionnel:

  > Elle m'a dit que la porte **serait** installée dans trois jours.
- Elle me l'a dit lundi mais aujourd'hui nous sommes samedi. Maintenant, l'événement est dans le passé *par rapport au moment de mon discours*. Cette fois, j'utilise l'imparfait

  > Elle m'a dit que la porte **était** installée dans trois jours.

Est-ce que ma compréhension est correcte? Si non, veuillez me dire pourquoi.

Comment: Le problème n'est pas vraiment soluble par une concordance de temps. Comme que tu t'y prennes en style indirect, *dans trois jours* sera interprété relativement au moment de l'élocution. Dans trois jours à compter non du moment où elle l'a dit mais à compter du moment où le locuteur raconte ce fait. Il faut tourner la phrase autrement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tant que l'action se situe dans le futur on peut utiliser soit le futur soit le conditionnel et alors on parle de conditionnel à valeur de futur:

- Elle m'a dit que la porte sera installée dans trois jours.
- Elle m'a dit que la porte serait installée dans trois jours.

Lorsque l'action est dans le passé on utilise encore le conditionnel mais en aucun cas le futur. On ne doit pas utiliser l'imparfait non plus. Comme la personne qui parle ne sait pas si l'installation a été faite ou non ou bien la présente comme une action seulement possible le mode doit être le conditionnel.
Par exemple, supposons que la personne sache très bien que la porte a été installée mais veuille affirmer emphatiquement à quelqu'un combien elle a confiance en la parole des responsables des portes; alors elle pourrait dire quelque chose comme suit:

Elle m'a dit que la porte serait installée dans trois jours et ça a été fait.