# First and second conditional in the same sentence

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, conditionnel

I was solving some exercises on Le conditionnel, and there is this one example I don't understand.

Mettre au temps voulu les infinitifs entre parenthèses :

> Si je trouve votre sœur, je l'(amener) ici, mais si je ne la trouvais pas, je la (faire) appeler par le haut-parleur.

Solution:

> Si je trouve votre sœur, je l'amènerai ici, mais si je ne la trouvais pas, je la ferais appeler par le haut-parleur.

I managed to write the correct solution, but I'm not sure I understand the meaning of this sentence. Why is there  *le présent* in the first subordinate clause (*si je trouve*), and then in the second one *(mais si je ne la trouvais pas)* why do we use *l'imparfait*? Wouldn't it mean something like *If I find your sister, I'll bring her here, but if I **didn't** find her (...)?*

To me it would make more sense if this sentence was phrased as:

> Si je trouve votre sœur, je l'amènerai ici, mais si je ne la **trouve** pas, je la **ferai** appeler par le haut-parleur.

Merci d'avance.

Comment: This is a question of "concordance des temps" (sequence of tenses ?) Maybe [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31376/concordance-des-temps-conditionnel-et-imparfait) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the tense used (conditionnel présent, ferais) is justified as the tense of "trouvais" is the so-called "imparfait en système hypothétique". Here is an example from a [web reference](https://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/les-valeurs-demploi-des-temps-simples-de-lindicatif.html);

> A) L'imparfait en système hypothétique :
>   Dans une subordonnée introduite par "si", l'imparfait marque le potentiel ou l'irréel du présent.
>
> - Si j'étais riche, je **voyagerais** autour du monde.

Nevertheless, the form you suggest is also right, since you replace that "imparfait en système hypothétique" with the "présent". There is then no difference.

The reason you use the future is a matter of correspondance, as it can be seen from this example in the same reference in the section "valeurs modales du présent".

> b) Le système hypothétique : le présent marque l'éventualité
>
> - S'il fait beau, nous visiterons le musée.

Let's add one detail: the present can also be used for the second verb and the last;

- Si je trouve votre sœur, je l'amène ici, mais si je ne la trouve pas, je la ferai appeler par le haut-parleur.